# Using over() function in R with Polygons and Raster

Tags: raster, r, polygon, overlay

I want to calculate the average rain by region using the `over` function in R but I am getting the error "unable to find an inherited method for function over for signature RasterLayer, SpatialPolygonsDataFrame". This is my code:

```
rain <- readOGR(dsn="/Users___.shp", layer="rain")
class(rain)
#SpatialPolygonsDataFrame

region <- readOGR(dsn="/Users___.shp", layer="region")
class(region)
#SpatialPolygonsDataFrame

s <- raster(ncol=90, nrow=90)
extent(s) <- extent(rain)
rain_raster <- rasterize(rain, s)
class(rain_raster)
#RasterLayer

test1 <- over(rain_raster, region, fn="mean")
#error: unable to find an inherited method for function ‘over’ for signature ‘"RasterLayer", "SpatialPolygonsDataFrame"
```

How can I calculate this average without getting this error?

Answer (score 0):

`over` doesn't do raster-polygon computations. You need something like `extract` from the `raster` package:

This will return the mean of all raster cells in each part of `region`:

```
 test1 <- raster::extract(rain_raster, region, fun=mean)
```

Comment: I tried using `extract` but I am getting an error.

Comment: If extract doesn't work, please edit your question and show us the problem there.